# Escaping quotes in Redshift query

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to refactor my code to PEP8 standards for readability but I'm struggling to escape quotes in my SQL queries.
I have 2 queries. The first is a simple SQL query. The second is a Redshift UNLOAD command.

```
query = '''SELECT * FROM redshift_table
           LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM redshift_view) v
           ON redshift_table.account_number = v.card_no
           WHERE timestamp < date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE)
           AND timestamp >=  (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')'''

unload = '''UNLOAD ('%s') to '%s'
            credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s'
            delimiter as '%s'parallel off ALLOWOVERWRITE''' % (query, s3_path, access_key, aws_secret, file_delimiter)
```

Because the sql query is imbedded inside the UNLOAD command, I can only make it work by escaping quotes by prepending them with 3 backslashes: 'day' becomes ///'day///'. 
This isn't ideal and I was wondering if there was a way around it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to insert backslash before quotes only inside unload command, using a escape function works. Here is an example.

```python
def escape_quote(value):
  return value.replace("'", "\\'")

query = '''SELECT * FROM redshift_table
           LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM redshift_view) v
           ON redshift_table.account_number = v.card_no
           WHERE timestamp < date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE)
           AND timestamp >=  (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')'''

unload = '''UNLOAD ('%s') to '%s'
            credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s'
            delimiter as '%s'parallel off ALLOWOVERWRITE''' % (escape_quote(query), s3_path, access_key, aws_secret, file_delimiter)
```

Comment: This is definitely an elegant solution. I was wondering however if there was a way to harness to power of psycopg2, which already performs escaping of sql queries, to avoid having to add extra code.

Comment: this does not consider quotes that are already escaped.  this code will effectively unescape it by escaping the backslash.  Read Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions for a standard regex to match and escape quoted strings while taking into consideration embedded escape characters.

Answer (score 2):

Masashi's answer won't always work, for example if there are already escaped strings in the query (e.g. in regular expressions).

For a more robust solution, you can take advantage of dollar quoting. The Redshift documentation points to [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-syntax-lexical.html) in the section "Dollar-quoted String Constants". Instead of escaping quotes manually, you can use dollar signs to quote your query like so:

```
unload = """UNLOAD ($$ %s $$) ...as""" % (query, ...)
```

Granted, this will also break if you use `$$` anywhere in your query. If you want to be really safe, use a random tag inside the dollar signs:

```
import uuid

# Leading underscore is necessary since this needs to be a valid
# identifier, i.e. can only start with a letter or underscore.
quote_tag = '_' + uuid.uuid4().hex

unload = 'UNLOAD ($%s$ %s $%s$) ...'.format(quote_tag, query, quote_tag, ...)
```

Comment: Do you know what happens if the query has backslashes in it? it is required to escape them as well?

Comment: If you're using dollar quoting, not that I know of.